# Python based static c analysis tools

Tags: c, static-analysis, python

I want to analyze some open-source `C` code, and I'm looking for a static analysis python library for `C`, preferably open-source. Any ideas/suggestions, based on your experience?

Comment: https://github.com/mre/awesome-static-analysis#cc

Comment: Yes, I saw the lists, I'm looking to hear also about some usage based experience.